# Parameters via Activity change

Tags: android, android-activity

I want the new activity to receive data dependning on which button a user pressed.

So for an example: User press button 2 -> Starts new Activity -> new Activity know which button was pressed.

Comment: use Intent Extra parameter or put it in bundle

Comment: why activity2 should know which button was pressed, in activity1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).So pass an int which is button id into the new Intent from FirstActivity as

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("key", buttonID); //Your buttonID
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Then use the id in your SecondActivity:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
if(b!= null){
    int value = b.getInt("key");
}
```